# java.lang.NullPointerException when orientation changed(Android Lifecycle)

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

Hello I have an Activity that should just count in each life cycle changed, so I develop like this but when orientation changed its show an exception:

**LOGCAT**

```
01-23 22:04:45.075: I/Lab-ActivityOne(7963): Entered the onCreate() method
01-23 22:04:45.085: I/Lab-ActivityOne(7963): Entered the onStart() method
01-23 22:04:45.085: I/Lab-ActivityOne(7963): Entered the onResume() method
01-23 22:04:45.185: D/libEGL(7963): loaded     /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
01-23 22:04:45.215: D/libEGL(7963): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
01-23 22:04:45.235: D/libEGL(7963): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
01-23 22:04:45.235: D/libEGL(7963): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
01-23 22:04:45.395: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(7963): <ConfigWindowMatch:1991>: Format RGBA_8888.
  01-23 22:04:45.846: D/OpenGLRenderer(7963): Enabling debug mode 0
  01-23 22:04:45.986: D/OpenGLRenderer(7963): has fontRender patch
 01-23 22:04:46.046: D/OpenGLRenderer(7963): has fontRender patch
01-23 22:04:54.815: D/OpenGLRenderer(7963): Flushing caches (mode 0)
01-23 22:04:54.825: I/Lab-ActivityOne(7963): Entered the onPause() method
01-23 22:04:54.825: I/Lab-ActivityOne(7963): YESSSSSSSSSSSS--1
01-23 22:04:54.825: I/Lab-ActivityOne(7963): Entered the onStop() method
01-23 22:04:54.825: I/Lab-ActivityOne(7963): Entered the onDestroy() method
01-23 22:04:54.835: D/memalloc(7963): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer    base:0x5217b000 size:4608000 offset:3072000
01-23 22:04:54.835: D/memalloc(7963): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x52cb2000 size:7557120 offset:6021120
01-23 22:04:54.985: I/Lab-ActivityOne(7963): ---null
 01-23 22:04:54.985: D/AndroidRuntime(7963): Shutting down VM

    01-23 22:04:54.995: E/AndroidRuntime(7963): Caused by:   java.lang.NullPointerException
    01-23 22:04:54.995: E/AndroidRuntime(7963):     at course.labs.activitylab.ActivityOne.onCreate(ActivityOne.java:126)
   01-23 22:04:54.995: E/AndroidRuntime(7963):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
   01-23 22:04:54.995: E/AndroidRuntime(7963):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
    01-23 22:04:54.995: E/AndroidRuntime(7963):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
     01-23 22:04:54.995: E/AndroidRuntime(7963):    ... 12 more
```

**My main activity:**

```
public class ActivityOne extends Activity {


private static final String RESTART_KEY = "restart";

private static final String RESUME_KEY = "resume";

private static final String START_KEY = "start";

private static final String CREATE_KEY = "create";



// String for LogCat documentation

private final static String TAG = "Lab-ActivityOne";







Hashtable count_info = new Hashtable();

int mCreate=0;
int mRestart=0;
int mStart=0;
int mResume=0;



TextView mTvCreate;
TextView mTvRestart;
TextView mTvStart;
TextView mTvResume;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);



    // TODO: Assign the appropriate TextViews to the TextView variables

    // Hint: Access the TextView by calling Activity's findViewById()

    // textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);






    mTvCreate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.create);
    mTvRestart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.restart);
    mTvStart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.start);
    mTvResume = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resume);       

    Button launchActivityTwoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLaunchActivityTwo); 


    launchActivityTwoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO:

            // Launch Activity Two

            // Hint: use Context's startActivity() method


            // Create an intent stating which Activity you would like to start



            // Launch the Activity using the intent


            Intent activity_two = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityTwo.class);   

            startActivity(activity_two);            
        }

    });



    // Check for previously saved state

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {


        // TODO:

        // Restore value of counters from saved state

        // Only need 4 lines of code, one for every count variable
        Log.i(TAG,"---"+count_info.get("onCreate"));

        mCreate = (Integer) count_info.get("onCreate"); 
        mStart = (Integer) count_info.get("onStart");
        mResume = (Integer) count_info.get("onResume");
        mRestart = (Integer) count_info.get("onRestart");   


    }


    // TODO: Emit LogCat message



    Log.i(TAG,"Entered the onCreate() method");

    // TODO:

    // Update the appropriate count variable

    mCreate++;

        // Update the user interface via the displayCounts() method




                displayCounts();

     }



// Lifecycle callback overrides


@Override

public void onStart() {

    super.onStart();


    // TODO: Emit LogCat message



    Log.i(TAG,"Entered the onStart() method");  
    // TODO:

    // Update the appropriate count variable

    mStart++;       
    // Update the user interface



    displayCounts();
}



@Override

public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();


    // TODO: Emit LogCat message



    Log.i(TAG,"Entered the onResume() method");     
    // TODO:

    // Update the appropriate count variable
    mResume++;

    // Update the user interface



displayCounts();    
    }



@Override

public void onPause() {

    super.onPause();


    // TODO: Emit LogCat message


    Log.i(TAG,"Entered the onPause() method");  
}



@Override

public void onStop() {

    super.onStop();


    // TODO: Emit LogCat message
    Log.i(TAG,"Entered the onStop() method");


}



    @Override

   public void onRestart() {

    super.onRestart();


    // TODO: Emit LogCat message



    Log.i(TAG,"Entered the onRestart() method");        
    // TODO:

    // Update the appropriate count variable

    mRestart++;     
    // Update the user interface




        displayCounts();
    }



    @Override

   public void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();


    // TODO: Emit LogCat message



    Log.i(TAG,"Entered the onDestroy() method");    
    }



   @Override

   public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // TODO:

    // Save state information with a collection of key-value pairs

    // 4 lines of code, one for every count variable







    count_info.put("onCreate", mCreate);
        count_info.put("onStart", mStart);
        count_info.put("onResume", mResume);
    count_info.put("onRestart", mRestart);
    Log.i(TAG,"YESSSSSSSSSSSS--"+count_info.get("onCreate"));

    }



    // Updates the displayed counters

   public void displayCounts() {


    mTvCreate.setText("onCreate() calls: " + mCreate);

    mTvStart.setText("onStart() calls: " + mStart);

    mTvResume.setText("onResume() calls: " + mResume);

    mTvRestart.setText("onRestart() calls: " + mRestart);


  }

}
```

**My Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/create"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/onCreate" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/onStart" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/resume"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/onResume" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/restart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/onRestart" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/bLaunchActivityTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button" />

           </LinearLayout>`
```

Comment: check your ActivityOne.java on line 126. you geting NullPointer maybe because you're trying to manipulate some View which is not initialized.

Comment: @PedroHawk I have checked ot work in other method but not in savedins!=null

Comment: @PedroHawk how to reformat code properly here?

Comment: Is this the line no 126 -> if (savedInstanceState != null) ?

Comment: I have null there mCreate = (Integer) count_info.get("onCreate");

Comment: @Amit mCreate = (Integer) count_info.get("onCreate");

Comment: your hashtable is null.

Comment: @Jessie try this outState.putInt("key", value)

Comment: if you don't save the state, count_info is empty, so get("onCreate") returns null, so mCreate++ throws a NPE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) put this:

```
savedInstanceState.putSerializable("KEY", count_info);
```

and in your on create this:

```
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

    count_info = (Hashtable) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("KEY");

//initialize variables here

}
else
    count_info = new Hashtable();
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
static Hashtable count_info = new Hashtable();
```

Comment: do you think in portait mode it return value but in landscpa Unfortunally stopped here mCreate = (Integer) count_info.get("onCreate");  maybe i dont create it properly

Comment: when you change your orientation, it re-creates the activity again.